# How Generate boot.oat

Tags: android, rom

I need modify android.policy.jar in Android L. I just have ROM and device, no aosp.

Now, I can decompiler boot.oat by oat2dex.jar, get dex like android.policy.dex/framework.dex ...

My preblem is that I do not know how to generate boot.oat after decompiler it.

I want to modify android.policy and then re-generate boot.oat, replace the original one.

Is there any one please help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

The `dex2oat` on-device compiler is used to compile the java libraries including the android.policy.jar. I did not explicitly test it, but the following might work for you:

You probably want to find out the cmd line args for `dex2oat` required to create an updates `boot.oat` that includes your changes. 
Fortunately, `boot.oat` stores the cmd line used to generate it in its header. You can use the `oatdump` binary (available on device, at least for AOSP builds) to dump the header and extract the correct cmd line args. Now issue this command again so that a new `boot.oat` is generated, this time including your modified policy jar. Make sure that the result is placed in the correct location so that it overwrites the previous version of `boot.oat`. After a reboot, the new `boot.oat` should be used everywhere.

Of course, I would recommend to only do this on a test device and make appropriate backups.

Once again, I did not test this, so it is possible that there are additional checks that detect changes in `boot.oat` so it might happen that it is again regenerated during boot.

Alternative paths in case this one does not work: 
- the boot.oat file needs to be recreated upon major version updates, so the system definitely knows how to do it. Try to find a way to trigger this.
- compile AOSP and print out the command lines used for `dex2oat` to see how the `boot.oat` compilation is done for AOSP. Custom ROMs might and will probably differ, but then you have at least a base configuration that you can start to tweak.

Hope this helps.